# Can't access SQLITE database Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've created a SQLite database when I call this method :

```
public boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, null);
        checkDB.close();
        return checkDB != null;
    }
```

I get this error:
**`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database`**

The DB is created, I could retrieve it from the emulator file explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openOrCreateDatabase(java.io.File,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory))

the first argument of **openOrCreateDatabase** is a ***file*** or a **path**.
And your line of code should look like this:

```
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME), null);
```

One more comment:  `checkDB != null` is always ***true*** in the current snippet of code.